Gnome extensions | 'native host has exited'
Running Chrome 126.0.6478.55 under AlmaLinux 8.xx (i.e., RHEL 8, CentOS 8,...). Gnome 3.32.2.
Have been using a few Gnome extensions for a while, but this morning, when I pull up chrome and point it at Gnome extensions, I get a 'Native host has exited' error. Tried uninstalling google-chrome-stable, and chrome-gnome-shell, and re-installing, but didn't 'solve' the problem. The few extensions I use all seem to be working. Whats odd, and likely related, when I try a few standalone extension managers, they all seem to say I have no extensions installed (which is not the case). And, I have AlmaLinux 9 running in a VM, and Gnome extensions comes up fine -- no 'Native host has exited' error'. Same with my Fedora 40 machines.
But, I use the AlmaLinux 8.xx box with some frequency, and would like to know what I could try to get the 'Native host has exited' error resolved.
Suggestions?
Thanks in advance...

I also tried Firefox on the same AlmaLinux 8 machine -- didn't help.  Only difference is that the error message is 'An unexpected error occurred' (as opposed to 'Native host has exited...' that I see using Chrome).
